# Серверный рендер страниц не на js

Tags: reactjs

Я хочу рендерить страницы на сервере, на php и java, но использовать react на клиенте, есть ли такая возможность?

Возможно есть инструмент для компилирования компонентов в шаблоны (например pug, jsp или просто html/xml), в которые можно вставить данные и отдать пользователю, а уже на его стороне навесить обработчики реакта

Я не хочу использовать node.js как сервер для рендера и не хочу выполнять js код в php/java

Если это невозможно, посоветуйте эффективный фреймворк с возможностью динамического изменения DOM при изменении данных, умеющий подсасываться к готовой html странице, которую можно рендерить любым способом

Comment: Чем плох `js` браузера? Принял с сервера, обновил элемент.

Comment: Я не говорил что js плох. Мне нужен SSR на PHP и Java

Comment: `Java`?  Вы определитесь вобоще, что вам нужно, то `js` не нужен, зато `Vue` нужен, а это вам что по вашему, не `js`? `Java` - это не `js`. И вообще, почему бы тогда просто не использовать сокеты? не ну если надо вуе, берите, в чем проблема? Или тупо `Angular` вообще используйте.

Comment: Мне видится странным ваш подход, если вы работаете с js на клиенте, то зачем вам на что-то другое на сервере? Зачем распыляться на другие языки? Для SSR используйте next.js и не мучайтесь.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую Vue.js так как он перерисовывает минимальное количество компонентов и поддерживает интеграцию сторонних библиотек. React.js, Vue.js очень быстрый, использует Virtual DOM, а также предоставляет реактивность и компонентную структуру.

Comment: Я могу рендерить страницы на php/java и уже на клиенте подключать vue и интерпретировать элементы как компоненты? Или он тоже завязан на каком-то js шаблонизаторе?

Comment: он интегрируется в проекты с использованием других JavaScript-библиотек, по поводу рендеринга стоит проверить.